# All queries to one MySQL table getting stuck

Tags: mysql

We have an issues that started to pop a couple of months ago, and it happens every 4-5 weeks. It happens on a specific table, which stores the sessions for a PHP (Zend Framework) app.

The issue is that all queries (INSERT, DELETE, UPDATE, SELECT) are really slow all of the sudden, and the number of connections to MySQL just go high (from 5 connections to more than 400 in a couple of seconds).

The table was at first with the MEMORY type, and we saw that MEMORY have the same behavior as MyISAM, it locks the whole table. Thinking it was the issue, we switched to InnoDB, and all was well for a couple of weeks. Sadly, the problem came back a couple of times even with InnoDB as the table type.

The SELECT are stuck on the "statistics" state, the UPDATE are stuck on the "Updating" state, same thing for DELETE and INSERT. We don't see any locks, the I/O is below 20%, and the CPU and memory load are good.

When the problem occurs, the table have between 5500 and 6500 rows (currently have 2912). Table definition:

```
-----------+-----------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field     | Type            | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+-----------+-----------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| id        | varbinary(32)   | NO   | PRI |         |       |
| modified  | int(11)         | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| lifetime  | int(11)         | YES  | MUL | NULL    |       |
| serialize | varbinary(8192) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+-----------+-----------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

Does anyone have seen that behavior? This is running MySQL 5.1.73 (latest version of 5.1) on CentOS.

Comment: Tell us more about the table, including layout, indexes and row counts.

Comment: MySQL will only use as much memory for InnoDB as you give it ([InnoDB buffer pool](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-buffer-pool.html)). So, memory can seem fine on system, yet MySQL is starving. If you ran out of room in memory, especially as the index grows (number of rows increased), you would see what you're describing.

Comment: innodb_buffer_pool_size is currently 8388608 bytes (8 MB). That sessions table is the only one using InnoDB, all of the others are MyISAM.

Comment: Our buffer pool size is measured in GBs. [Raise it](http://www.percona.com/blog/2007/11/03/choosing-innodb_buffer_pool_size/).